# SVN copy between URL's fails

Tags: svn

I am trying to create a tag on SVN 1.7 .

While trying:
`svn copy svn://svn-rep.domain/dev/trunk svn://svn-rep.domain/dev/tags/product`

I get the following error:
`svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or
 --file (-F) options
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found`

And when adding a message:
`svn copy svn://svn-rep.domain/dev/trunk svn://svn-rep.domain/dev/tags/product -m 'message'`

I get this error:
`svn: E205009: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am confused by your urls: is `svn-host` just a random folder name or a remote system where the repository lives? In other words: is it a local repository or a remote one?

Comment: Thank you for your comment arkascha. It is a remote server. I will edit the question (as soon as I find how to...)

Comment: You cannot use the `svn` protocol scheme to address a remote repository, you need either `http`/`https` or `svn+ssh`. At least it used to be so in earlier versions...

Comment: It's a remote server on our company's local network. Using the svn protocol works for other operations (commit, info etc.)

Comment: @arkascha, you're thinking of the `file` protocol scheme. `svnserve` (`svn` scheme) has supported remote access since 1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the only thing to do for it to work is to change the (') around the message to (").

And to think that kept me busy for so long...